# Flutter Error : Package io.flutter.plugins.webviewflutter does not exists

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, webview-flutter

I get an error message while running a Flutter project. I tried using webview_flutter(1.0.7) plugin with Flutter 1.22.5(stable) and Flutter 1.26.0-2.0.pre.167.

This is a fresh new project with only webview_flutter plugin dependency.

[image: Error Screenshot]

I am getting the above error that package webviewflutter does not exists.

Please help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if you made the correct entry for the package in your **`pubspec.yaml`** and after that does **`get`** run successfully.

Just a tip:
It is better to paste the error text, rather than a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, I added the plugin in pubspec.yaml and installed it by flutter pub get successfully. Also this plugin gets added in PluginRegistrant java file too. But at the time of build, this error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wasn't of help. Sorry.